# Why are un-requested packages removed (docker build)?

Tags: docker

So, I'm building my docker with the following Dockerfile

```
# dummy base, which contains R
ARG MY_BASE_IMAGE=r-base
FROM ${MY_BASE_IMAGE}

ARG KING_URL="http://people.virginia.edu/~wc9c/KING/executables/Linux-king215.tar.gz"
ARG PLINK2_URL="https://github.com/chrchang/plink-ng/releases/download/2019/plink2_linux_x86_64_20190107.zip"
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get -qqy update --fix-missing && \
    apt-get -qqy dist-upgrade && \
    apt-get -qqy install --no-install-recommends \
                 wget unzip && \
    cd /tmp && \
    wget -q ${KING_URL} && \
    tar -xzf Linux-king215.tar.gz -C /usr/local/bin && \
    wget -q ${PLINK2_URL} && \
    unzip plink2_linux_x86_64_20190107.zip -d /usr/local/bin && \
    cd -- && \
    apt-get -qqy remove wget unzip && \
    rm -rf /tmp/* \
           /var/tmp/* \
           /var/cache/apt/* \
           /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
           /usr/share/man/?? \
           /usr/share/man/??_*
```

However, this seems to remove R, unless I explicitly remove the line `apt-get -qqy remove wget unzip`.

I'm having difficulty understanding why. Help much appreciated!

---

**UPDATE**

I've dug deeper, and fount that if I run `apt-get -qqy remove wget`, things go OK.

**BUT**! If I `apt-get -qqy remove unzip`, back to the old weird behavior of the following:

```
Removing littler (0.3.7-2) ...
Removing r-base (3.5.3-1) ...
Removing r-recommended (3.5.3-1) ...
Removing r-cran-mgcv (1.8-28-1) ...
Removing r-base-dev (3.5.3-1) ...
Removing r-cran-littler (0.3.7-2) ...
Removing r-cran-boot (1.3-20-2) ...
Removing r-cran-class (7.3-15-1) ...
Removing r-cran-cluster (2.0.7-1-1+b3) ...
Removing r-cran-codetools (0.2-16-1) ...
Removing r-cran-foreign (0.8.71-1) ...
Removing r-cran-kernsmooth (2.23-15-3+b4) ...
Removing r-cran-nlme (3.1.137-1+b3) ...
Removing r-cran-mass (7.3-51.1-1) ...
Removing r-cran-nnet (7.3-12-2+b2) ...
Removing r-cran-rpart (4.1-13-1+b1) ...
Removing r-cran-spatial (7.3-11-2+b2) ...
Removing r-cran-survival (2.43-3-1) ...
Removing r-cran-matrix (1.2-17-1) ...
Removing r-cran-lattice (0.20-38-1) ...
Removing r-base-core (3.5.3-1) ...
Removing unzip (6.0-22) ...
```

Comment: What do you mean by **remove R** ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meant R seems to be uninstalled by the ‘remove’ command, even though I did not ask for that.

Comment: It sounds as if `unzip` is a dependency of the `R` package. Since you are asking apt to remove `unzip`, it will also need to remove anything that depends on `unzip`. That is how package managers usually work.

Comment: That's right @larsks! I was just about to report back on this. Do you mind writing a formal answer? Honestly I was surprised R depends on unzip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as if unzip is a dependency of the R package. Since you are asking apt to remove unzip, it will also need to remove anything that depends on unzip.  This is typical behavior for a package manager.

You can see the dependency tree for a package with the `apt-cache dotty` command, which will output the dependencies in [dot format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_(graph_description_language)). Running `apt-cache dotty r-base` shows:

```
r-base -> r-base-core
r-base-core -> unzip
```